# Read SPACE without ENTER as input from terminal

Tags: go, terminal, stdin

I had a CLI program which will ask user to type ENTER to continue and OTHER keys to abort.

```
for {
    show() // list one page

    fmt.Printf("Press ENTER to show next page, press any other key then Enter to quit")
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    if strings.Trim(input, " ") == "" {
        continue
    } else {
        break
    }
}
```

I want to improve user experience: instead of "ENTER or press something then ENTER", how can I make it **"Press SPACE to show next page, press q to quit"**, just like Linux command "more" and others.

To make it clear:

- The existing control to continue is "ENTER", I want to use "SPACE" (just SPACE, not SPACE+ENTER);
- The existing control to quit is "any key + ENTER", I want to use "q" (just q, not q+ENTER)

Comment: It can't be done easy with stdlib. You most likely need thirdparty library, some equivalent of GNU readline like https://github.com/chzyer/readline or https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built in shell command `read -n1 -r -p "Press SPACE to show next page, press q to quit" key`. Possibly you could exec that.

For a more full featured golang solution, see `github.com/nsf/termbox-go`. Good example: https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-get-ascii-code-from-a-key-press-cross-platform-example

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution with `github.com/nsf/termbox-go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    tb "github.com/nsf/termbox-go"
)

func main() {
    err := tb.Init()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer tb.Close()
    for {
        fmt.Println("Press any key")
        event := tb.PollEvent()
        switch {
        case event.Ch == 'a':
            fmt.Println("a")
        case event.Key == tb.KeyEsc:
            fmt.Println("Bye!")
            return
        case event.Key == tb.KeySpace:
            fmt.Println("ANY KEY! You pressed SPACE!")
        case event.Key == tb.KeyEnter:
            fmt.Println("ANY KEY! You pressed ENTER!")
        default:
            fmt.Println("Any key.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forget `tb.Close()`, so it behaves wired after program exit. But anyway, thanks for this example